# Очень долго Gradle Build Running

Tags: android-studio, android

После последнего обновления студии стало очень долго выполняться (3-40мин) "Gradle Build Running" перед запуском приложения.

Как это лечить?

Текущая версия студии: 1.3.2

Comment: Это происходит каждый раз при запуске IDE или единоразово для одного проекта? Насколько крупный проект? Какое железо и ОС ?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Добавьте версии самого Gradle и плагина для Android. Это важнее чем версия самой студии.

Answer (score 4):

попробуйте добавить в корень проекта файл `gradle.properties` с таким содержимым

`org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true`

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая ситуация была, когда я писал проект на нескольких машинах (дом/работа) и одна из них была подключена через прокси - в результате на одной открытие/компиляция происходила быстро, а на другой как у вас 30-40 минут. Исходя из наблюдений, пришел к выводу, что грэдл во время работы подключается к своим каким-то облачным сервисам.
Проверьте доступность инэта для студии (может фаерволл блокирует или антивирус), а также вышеупомянутый gradle.properties (если машина не использует прокси, то в этом файле не должно быть ни одной строки на эту тему)

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая проблема. Как на скриншоте. Висело такое сообщение очень долго [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Такое происходит, когда плохая скорость интернета или плохая скорость на серверах Gradle. Дело в том, что если первый раз запускаешь проект, при таком поведении студии, она закачивает сюда /Users/nameuser/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-3.3-all.zip архив "gradle-3.3-all.zip". Что продолжаться может очень долго.

Есть выход скачать с сервера файл [вручную](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip)  и вставить его сюда (вместо точек): /Users/nameuser/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/....

или попробовать подключиться через прокси.

Такая же история, если открываете проекты собранные на старых версиях  gradle, таких как gradle-2.10-all и т.д., если открываете проект первый раз на этой сборке, то Android Studio будет закачивать архив gradle с сервера.