# Проблема при компиляции - com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException

Tags: android, android-studio, юнит-тесты, gradle, robolectric

Знаю, что такой вопрос уже [был](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454720/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE-gradle-build-running), но его автор задал вопрос без подробностей и не получил ответа.

Создал проект с библиотекой, рядом создал модуль приложения для проверки библиотеки. Хочу все это дело тестировать с помощью Robolectric. Добавил его в зависимости. После этого проект начал долго компилироваться. Если убрать Robolectric, все нормально собирается.

Добавление multidex в defaultConfig и подключение библиотеки support.multidex не помогают.

Вот файл build.gradle приложения:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "imangazaliev.quickmenusample"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
}
```

А еще выскакивает такая ошибка:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileLint
:library:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:library:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:checkReleaseManifest
:library:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareReleaseDependencies
:library:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:library:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareQuickMenuLibraryLibraryUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 18.905 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: нужно указывать ```testCompile``` вместо ```compile``` для библиотек которые нужны для ```unit``` тестов, вот здесь можете посмотреть как создать тест - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/478829/181119

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта ошибка, похоже, вызвана тем, что вместе с этой библиотекой вы превысили лимит количества методов в проекте - `65536`.

**Решить можно:**

1. Используя решение гугла для этой проблемы [Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/multidex.html). [Кратко](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515860/3212712): добавьте вот это в `gradle`:

   ```
   android {

       defaultConfig {
           ...

           // Enabling multidex support.
           multiDexEnabled true
       }
       ...
   }

   dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
   }
   ```

Добавьте аттрибут в тег `Application` `Manifest`-a:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

И, если используете свой класс `Application` то надо расширять его теперь от `MultiDexApplication`

2. Как помянуто в комментах @temq, указывать `testCompile` вместо `compile` для библиотек которые нужны для unit тестов
3. Удалить все остальные библиотеки чтобы войти в лимит)

Comment: Очень круто! Мне помогло! Сегодня просто часов 6 сидел вычитывал документацию... От куда вы это знаете? Как находите ответы? А у меня еще вопрос, я добавил только то, что вы рекомендуете для gradle в самом начале вашего ответа попробовал запустить и все заработало)) я даже сначала не поверил)) Так вот вопрос, нужно ли добавлять строки в манифест и все остальное если у меня и так работает?