# Упал Gradle после импорта GPGS

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

IDE: Android Studio

Использовал этот гайд: https://habrahabr.ru/post/238327/ для подключения в свой проект сервисов гугл. Импортнул либу (ProjectStructure -> android -> Dependencies -> com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0 - > [Scope]: Compile), дальше в Манифесте добавил необходимые строки (из гайда), и тут Грэдл сломался:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':android:dexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 2

Делал Clean Project, Rebuild Project, перезапускал студию, перезагружал машину, с памятью всё ок, выше 92% не используется, что делать - не знаю.

Вот лог Gradle:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:android:assembleDebug]
:android:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android:checkDebugManifest
:android:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareDebugDependencies
:android:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:android:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:android:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:android:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:android:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:android:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:android:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:android:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:android:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:android:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:android:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:android:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:android:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:android:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:android:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:android:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:android:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 45.63 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

И код самого gradle.build:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    compileSdkVersion 23
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if (outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}
task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.dailytoys.universalrace.android/com.dailytoys.universalrace.android.AndroidLauncher'
}
// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}
// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Что посоветуете?

Comment: Убрал из Dependencies либу и убрал из манифеста строки:
    <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Приложение сбилдилось и запустилось. 
Но всё-таки, хотелось бы подключить GPGS, в чём проблема? Как решить?

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы вместе с этой библиотекой превысили лимит на кол-во методов в проекте. Их должно быть не более ~65K. Решение по [ссылке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482874/17609)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо за ответ. И прошу прощения за повтор. Дело в том, что я искал решение на англоязычном stackoverflow, и найденные решения не помогли.

Comment: То, что вопрос - повтор не страшно) Это обычная ситуация. Закрытие вопроса как дубликата сделано для того, чтобы по разному сформулированные вопросы по проблеме, имеющей где-то решение, все ссылались на один ответ) А так вам надо было искать `dexindexoverflowexception android` (название ошибки из вашего лога) и получить вот этот ответ: [тык](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26515860/3212712)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вам точно нужны все сервисы? Скорее всего вам нужна только конкретная библиотека, есть возможность подключать отдельный функционал для пушей, отдельно для гугл диска, отдельно для локации и т.д.

Подробная таблица здесь - https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Спасибо за совет.