# Проблема с подключением библиотек

Tags: java, android, android-library

Пытаюсь подключить  библиотеки, первых две нужны для работы третьей

```
compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.8.5'
compile files('libs/autobahn-0.5.0.jar')
```

Делаю по туториалу http://autobahn.ws/android/gettingstarted.html

при подключении библиотек все норм, Gradle говорит что  проэкт собрался но, есть две красные строки

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

А при попытке запустить проект получаю это:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:484)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:261)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:473)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:161)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)



 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Вы превысили лимит кол-ва методов в приложении (65536 шт.). Возможные решения [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482874/17609)

Comment: Интересный момент что отключив эти три библиотеки приложение запустилось и ВебСокет заработал, как такое может быть?

Comment: Э-э-э... Какие сокеты?.. Я ничего про сокеты не знаю...

Comment: да эт я про библиотеку которую подключал autobahn-0.5.0.jar, как такое может быть ?

Comment: Ну так вы убрали эти библиотеки, методов стало меньше, приложение стало запускаться. То что вы не используете методы еще не означает что они не включаются в dex файл.

Comment: Просто как получилось  так что  я подключил библиотеки ->> написал класс который их использует ->> попробовал запустить - не получилось ->> отключил библиотеки ->> приложение запустилось  и классы где я использовал объекты из ранее отключенных  библиотек заработали, я наверное чего то не понимаю.