# Ошибка после обновления версии SDK до 25

Tags: java, android

Моё приложение использовало GCM сервис пуш уведомления. Всё работало нормально, пока я не обновил недавно версию SDK до 25

Примерно так выглядел файл app gradle:

```xml
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.frienddime.frienddime"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 107
        versionName "1.2.3"
    }
 ...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

}
```

И вот после обновления стала вылетать вот эта ошибка. Строка кода, на которую указывает ошибка это как раз то место где сервис регистрации GCM пытается получить токен GCM.

```xml
FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[]
 java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>:(Ljava/lang/String;)V from class com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzdL(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
     at com.frienddime.frienddime.GCMRegistrationIntentService.registerGCM(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:31)
     at com.frienddime.frienddime.GCMRegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:24)
     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Я попробовал поменять compileSdkVersion 25, buildToolsVersion "25.0.0", targetSdkVersion 25. Затем я нашёл в гугле что это дело в     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0', что мол надо поменять на последнюю версию. Однако я попытался изменить на ту что рекомендовалась 9.8.0, но в результате грэйдл выдал ошибку, что эта версия несовместима с остальными библиотеками. Я попробовал самую последнюю версию 10.0.1, но то же самое. Я поменял версии у com.android.support на 25.1.0 и это тоже не помогло.

Почему происходит данная ошибка и как её решить?

Comment: Попрбуйте ещё раз повысить версии всех либ, compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion и targetSdkVersion, а также перенести apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' в конец файла

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сделал, но не помогло, при синхронизации пишет: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я в файл gradle Project вставил classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' теперь грэйдл синхронизируется без ошибок, но при запуске проекта теперь выдаёт вот это Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationExceptio

Comment: У вас превышение кол-ва методов. Решение тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482874/17609 А также по приведённой вами же ссылки, которая есть в вашем же логе вашей же ошибки

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб попробовал я так сделать, но теперь почему-то при запуске грэйдл бесконечно грузится.

Comment: У вас что-то глючит. Единственное, что можно посоветовать - ещё раз с нуля всё сделать и, может быть, всё переустановить. Лично у меня всё всегда сразу работает если следовать докам